# Nuxt.js: How to reference page data from a layout? (e.g., to populate og:title tags)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-meta

I'm using Nuxt.js to generate static pages. I want each page to have a unique `<title>` tag and `<meta property="og:title" ... >` tag.

### Current implementation

I currently have an ugly solution that generates these tags. I have two pages that look like this:

#### `pages/foo.vue`

```js
export default {
  head: {
    title: 'Foo',
    meta: [
      {
        property: 'og:title',
        content: 'Foo',
      },
    ],
  }
};
```

#### `pages/bar.vue`

```js
export default {
  head: {
    title: 'Bar',
    meta: [
      {
        property: 'og:title',
        content: 'Bar',
      },
    ],
  }
};
```

### Problem

This correctly generates `<meta property="og:title" ...>` tags for each of my pages, but it forces me to include redundant code on all of my pages. My `og:title` tag always matches my `<title>` tag, so it makes no sense to redefine each of them independently on every page.

### Desired solution

I'd love a solution that allows me to define the `og:title` tag in my `layouts/default.vue` file or even in `nuxt.config.js`. Something like this:

#### `layouts/default.vue`

```js
export default {
  head() {
    return {
      meta: [
        {
          property: 'og:title',
          content: this.$page.head.title, // <-- This variable doesn't really exist
        }
      ],
    };
  },
};
```

#### `pages/foo.vue`

```js
export default {
  head: { title: 'Foo' }
};
```

#### `pages/bar.vue`

```js
export default {
  head: { title: 'Bar' }
};
```

### Question

Is is possible to eliminate the boilerplate here?

More generally, is it possible for Nuxt layouts to reference page-specific data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Layout.vue` cannot directly access to the nuxt data from a `Page.vue`.
You have to use a `Store` in order to share data between them.
See https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/

---

About your initial request, you can use a `Mixin` to share your meta configuration on each `Page.vue`.
See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

eg.

```js
// mixins/meta.vue

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      title: null,
      description: null
    }
  },
  head () {
   return {
     title = this.title
     meta = [
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: this.description },
      { hid: 'og:title', property: 'og:title', content: this.title },
      // ...
    ]
  }
}
</script>
```

```js
// <Page>.vue with local mixin

<script>
import Meta from '~/mixins/meta'

export default {
  mixins: [Meta], // local mixin
  asyncData () {
    return {
      title: "Foo",
      description: "lorem ipsum",
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

or create a global mixin with a Nuxt plugin:

```js
// plugins/meta.js

import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.mixin({
  data: { // ... }
  head: { // ...}
})
```

and declare your new plugin to apply on each Page:

```js
// nuxt.config.js

plugins: ['~/plugins/meta'],
```

Comment: Thanks! I applied this to my hello-world-vue-static project: https://github.com/mtlynch/hello-world-vue-static/pull/29